# How we will use uuid in AltBeacon Android

Tags: java, android

i am implementing beacon first time in my project and confused about UUid ,major ,minor and how we will be use it with Region class.

want to know about actual feature of it.

Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", Identifier.parse("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), null, null); this one what should we have to pass in it and use of this line –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXAMPLE**

Say you are a Museum who has bought 1000 Beacons. All 1000 beacons use the same UUID which tells end-users that these beacons are owned by the Museum.

This museum has 5 exhibitions running, so the museum assigns a Major value of 1 through 5 to identify beacons assigned to a particular exhibit. So there are now 5 groups of beacons with an assigned major value of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

Now let’s say there are 200 paintings and sculptures within each exhibition. All the exhibits are assigned an Beacon to deliver unique information about each piece, so you use the Minor value to distinguish between each Beacon.

So there are now 5 groups with 200 Beacons each, and each beacon is assigned a minor value of 1 through 200.

**Defining regions**

A beacon region can be defined in three ways:

With only UUID: it consists of all beacons with a given UUID.

With UUID and Major: it consists of all beacons using a specific combination of UUID and Major.

With UUID, Major and Minor: it consists of only a single beacon.

**EDIT**

```
public Region(String uniqueId,
  Identifier id1,
  Identifier id2,
  Identifier id3)
```

Constructs a new Region object to be used for Ranging or Monitoring
Parameters:

uniqueId - - A unique identifier used to later cancel Ranging and Monitoring, or change the region being Ranged/Monitored

id1 - - most significant identifier (can be null)

id2 - - second most significant identifier (can be null)

id3 - - third most significant identifier (can be null)

Source: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/Region.html

Example here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx bro its helped me to understand working concept but i have  a line and want to know about actual feature of it.  Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                Identifier.parse("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), null, null); this one what should we have to pass in it and use of this line

Comment: Thx broo awesome explanation .